# Battery 100% but work as 0%

Tags: 18.04, power-management, battery, bios, tlp

I'm on Ubuntu and bought this battery since 5 months only .. now I'm facing problem with it .. i found the led of battery is on and charge with 100 % but when i plug out the charger .. laptop is off 
i tried to solve it by similar posts here but it didn't work .. i check out the bios -> configuration but didn't find disable update battery
i check by this command

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

and got

```
native-path:          BAT0
vendor:               Lenovo IdeaPad
serial:               BAT20101001
power supply:         yes
updated:              Tue 24 Dec 2019 03:35:08 AM EET (5 seconds ago)
has history:          yes
has statistics:       yes
battery
present:             yes
rechargeable:        yes
state:               fully-charged
warning-level:       none
energy:              18.01 Wh
energy-empty:        0 Wh
energy-full:         18.01 Wh
energy-full-design:  31.68 Wh
energy-rate:         0 W
voltage:             16.299 V
percentage:          100%
capacity:            56.8497%
icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'
History (charge):
1577151295  100.000 fully-charged
1577151295  0.000   unknown
History (rate):
1577151295  0.000   unknown
```

i check `/proc/acpi` but didn't find battery folder

i hope i can find solution

Comment: You haven't specifically mentioned your release, however you tagged 14.04.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL & thus off-topic, Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is off-topic as all ESM releases are being supported only by Canonical through Ubuntu Advantage. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  Only questions specific about moving to a supported release of Ubuntu are on-topic for EOL/ESM releases.

Comment: This seems a lot like a hardware problem instead of an Ubuntu issue. If your laptop instantly powers off when you unplug it, then the battery has no charge. Ubuntu does not command your laptop charging; it merely reports the status. If the battery were reporting a very low charge, Ubuntu can trigger a system shutdown...but that's still the battery (hardware) as the cause.

Comment: sorry i'm on 18.04 .. i mentioned wrong version .. is that any problem with i posted ?

Comment: having same problem. As soon as I unplug my laptop it turns off, doesn't even shutdown. It is not hardware issue I am sure of that because I replaced my battery with a new one after I got this problem. I also test with booting into windows. The problem seems to occur only on Ubuntu.

Comment: @UsamaZafar Thanks for replying , so what can i do for this .. i'm using only Ubuntu on my work

Comment: @user1 I really don't know, I came here looking for a solution as well. :(